# Conversion of a simple Python Neural Network to a Haskell implementation

Tags: haskell, neural-network

I started with [this code](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) and modified and expanded it in Python. As an exercise/challenge to myself I decided to covert the original to Haskell. I either write imperatively or functionally. This is the first time I have tried converting from one logic to another.  I ran into a lot of little issue along the way. I aimed to just get it to work and I want to make it work better now.

```
import Data.List
import System.Random
import Data.Matrix hiding (transpose, trace)
import Debug.Trace

flipSign::Num a => a -> a
flipSign x = (-1) * x 

nonlin:: Bool -> Double ->   Double
nonlin True x = x*(1.0-x)
nonlin False x =  1.0 / (1.0 + (exp $ flipSign x))

randomList :: (Random a) => Int -> [a]
randomList seed = randoms (mkStdGen seed)

sample:: [[Double]]
sample = map (map fromIntegral)[ [0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1] ]
answers:: [[Double]]
answers = transpose $ map (map fromIntegral) [[0,0,1,1]]

syn0:: [[Double]]
syn0 = [[x] | x<- take 3 (randomList 42 :: [Double])]

dotp:: [[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> [[Double]]
dotp x y = toLists newMatrix
    where
        mx = fromLists x
        my = fromLists y
        newMatrix = multStd mx my

nextGeneration::[[Double]] -> [[Double]] -> ([[Double]], [[Double]]) -> ([[Double]],[[Double]])
nextGeneration x labels syn0_l1 = (new_syn0, l1)
    where
        l0 = x
        syn0 = fst syn0_l1
        l1 = map (map $ nonlin False) $ dotp l0 syn0 
        l1_error = zipWith (zipWith (-)) labels l1
        l1_delta = zipWith (zipWith (*)) l1_error $ map (map (nonlin True)) l1 
        new_syn0 = zipWith (zipWith (+)) syn0 $ dotp (transpose l0) l1_delta 

generations::([[Double]] -> [[Double]]) -> [[Double]] -> Int -> [[Double]]
generations _ end 0 = end
generations fun weights count = generations fun (fun weights) (count - 1)

main = print $ snd $ iterate (nextGeneration sample answers ) (syn0, [[]] ) !!10000
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You often switch between matrices and lists in the `dotp` function. Since that is an essential part of your code called every iteration and your data *is* a matrix, you should be using matrices everywhere.

In the [documentation](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.8/matrix-0.3.4.4/Data-Matrix.html) is noted, that there is a functor instance. That means you can use the function `fmap` on the matrix, which (in this case) maps a function over every cell. This means you can swap `map (map fromIntegral)` with `fmap fromIntegral`. The equivalent to `zipWith (zipWith ..)` is called `elementwise`.

The `generations` function doesn't seem to be called: you can avoid having dead code by compiling with warnings enabled, `-Wall`. The `flipSign` function is predefined and called `negate`.

I have changed `nonlin` to make the variable explicit, otherwise it wouldn't be clear what this Bool actually does. Furthermore, I have added some comments.

Finally, I have changed `nextGeneration` as there is no need to carry the `l1` variable if it isn't needed by the next step. I've extracted that into a function (and so have to take the 9999th iteration in `main`).

Here is my version of the code:

```
import System.Random (randoms, mkStdGen)
import Data.Matrix

-- | input dataset
sample :: Matrix Double
sample = fmap fromIntegral $ fromLists
    [ [0,0,1]
    , [0,1,1]
    , [1,0,1]
    , [1,1,1]
    ]

-- | output dataset
answers :: Matrix Double
answers = transpose (fmap fromIntegral output)
    where
        output = fromLists [[0,0,1,1]]

-- | sigmoid function
nonlin :: Bool -> Double -> Double
nonlin derivative x = if derivative then x * (1.0 - x)
                                    else 1.0 / (1.0 + (exp (negate x)))

layer1 :: Matrix Double -> Matrix Double -> Matrix Double
layer1 l0 syn0 = fmap (nonlin False) (multStd l0 syn0)

nextGeneration :: Matrix Double -> Matrix Double
nextGeneration syn0 = new_syn0
    where
        -- forward propagation
        l1 = layer1 sample syn0

        -- how much did we miss?
        l1_error = elementwise (-) answers l1

        -- multiply how much we missed by the
        -- slope of the sigmoid at the values in l1
        l1_delta = elementwise (*) l1_error (fmap (nonlin True) l1)

        -- update weights
        new_syn0 = elementwise (+) syn0 (multStd (transpose sample) l1_delta)

main = do
    putStrLn "Output After Training:"
    print (layer1 sample result)
        where
            start = fromList 3 1 (randoms (mkStdGen 42))
            generations = iterate nextGeneration start
            result = generations !! 9999
```

Comment: You had some great suggestions! Only thing I didn't like was that you moved sample and answers fully into the function. The problem with that is it makes it harder if I want to apply the same function to multiple sets of different data. I'll upload my new version in a bit.

Comment: The `fromIntegral` calls aren't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Have some refactoring!

```
import Data.List
import System.Random
import Data.Matrix
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

nextGeneration:: Matrix Double -> Matrix Double -> Matrix Double -> (Matrix Double, Matrix Double)
nextGeneration l0 labels syn0 = (new_syn0, l1) where
  l1 = (\x -> 1 / (1 + exp (-x))) <$> multStd l0 syn0 
  l1_error = elementwise (-) labels l1
  l1_delta = elementwise (*) l1_error $ (\x -> x * (1 - x)) <$> l1 
  new_syn0 = elementwise (+) syn0 $ multStd (transpose l0) l1_delta 

main = do
  syn0 <- transpose . fromLists . (:[]) <$> replicateM 3 randomIO :: IO (Matrix Double)
  let sample = fromLists [[0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]]     ::     Matrix Double
      answers = transpose $ fromLists [[0,0,1,1]]                 ::     Matrix Double
  print $ last $ evalState (replicateM 10000 $ state $ nextGeneration sample answers) syn0
```

Comment: Wow you made this program small. That is awesome! I had a few question I was hoping you could answer. What does the `:: Matrix Double` do? I have seen it in other programs, but I am a little fuzzy on it. Why RandomIO over just plain random?

Comment: @error_null_pointer that's from `Data.Matrix`. You did check the contents of that module, right?

Comment: @Gurkenglas that's not a review, but an alternative solution.

Comment: ":: Matrix Double" is the anologon to ":: [[Double]]" that we use after fromLists made it not be a [[Double]] anymore; it allows us to declare a type signature for sample/answers without using another line for it. I'm using IO because we're already in an IO block and randomIO does the work of generating a StdGen for us. (And not the same one each time!) Zeta, I did have some verbal commentary at first, but then found it superfluous to just pasting the mostly self-explanatory code.